# Prove that this limit converges uniformly on compact subsets of Open Unit Disc

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

This question was asked in my complex analysis quiz and I was unable to solve it. So, I am asking it here

> Question: Let $\{ f_n \}\subset H(D) $ , where $D$ is an open unit disc. Assume that $f_n(D) \subset D\setminus \{0\}$ for every $n$ and that $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $f_n(a) =0$ where $a$ is the center of disc $D.$ Then prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n (z) =0 $ uniformly on compact subsets of $D.$

Attempt: $f_n$ is bounded on this disc as domain. But that doesn't ring any bell as to why limit should go to $0$ uniformly.

Can anyone please shed some light on which result should be used?

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you required to prove uniform convergence or un-. convergence on the compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: @Caffeine compact subsets of D. Thanks, I am editing it. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: Do you know Montel’s theorem for normal families?

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho No that wasn't covered in the course

Answer (score 1):

Assume, WLOG, that $a=0$.
First proof:
It is easy to see that $u_n(z)=-\ln(|f_n|)$ is a positive harmonic function, and thus we can apply Harnak's inequalities in the disc of radius $r<R<1$:

$$\frac{R-r}{R+r}u_n(0)\le u_n(z)\le \frac{R+r}{R-r}u_n(0)\\
\frac{R-r}{R+r}\ln(|f_n(0)|)\ge\ln(|f_n|)\ge\frac{R+r}{R-r}\ln(|f_n(0)|)\\
|f_n(0)|^{C_r}\ge |f_n(z)|\ge |f_n(0)|^{c_r}$$

convergence easily follows.

Second proof:
Assume that $f_n(0)\in\mathbb{R}^+$;  $f_n(\mathbb{D})\neq \mathbb{D}-\{0\}$ and thus we can write $g_n(z):=\ln(f_n)$; $g_n(0)<0$.

We can now apply Herglotz inequalities (see the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823493/sum-n-0-inftyf-nz3-converges-uniformly-on-z-le-1-2+) for an hint about the derivation of the inequalities), obtaining

$$\frac{1-r}{1+r}\le \left|\frac{g_n(z)}{g_n(0)}\right|\le \frac{1+r}{1-r}$$

Since $g_n(0)\to -\infty$, for every compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$, $g_n(z)\to -\infty$ uniformly on the compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$, and $f_n\to 0$

Comment: Can you please tell how $u_n(z)= -(ln|f_n|)$ is harmonic? How did you deduced that?

Comment: Can you please reply to my above question asked in comments?

Comment: @James This is one way to prove it: it suffices to prove that$\partial_z\partial_{\bar z}\ln(|f_n|)=0$. Expanding the modulus and multiplying by $2$ we get $\partial_\bar{z}\partial_z\ln(\bar{f}_n)+\partial_z\partial_{\bar{z}}\ln(f_n)$. As $\ln(f_n)$ is holomorphic, the second term is zero. Now by chain rule the first term is zero too and the result is proved.