# How to prove $\frac{1-r}{1+r}\leq |\frac{z f^\prime (z)}{f(z)}| \leq\frac{1+r}{1-r} $ for each $f\in S$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

[image]

The proof is given in **Univalent Functions. *by* P. L. Duren**. What I don't understand is how the last inequality in the proof proves (7) because the term in the modulus in the last inequality is the inverse of the term in the modulus of (7).

Comment: Apply the inverse to the last inequality. You will  get $(7)$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, but then the bounds reverse also and thus it differs from bounds in (7).

Comment: When $0<a\le b\le c$ then $a^{-1}\ge b^{-1}\ge c^{-1}.$

Comment: How is the functional space $S$ defined ?

Comment: Connected: the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3830025/305862

Comment: @JeanMarie: Most probably this: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchlichtFunction.html

Comment: @Martin R Thanks, "S" like "schlicht" : I should have guessed in reference to the german origin of this part of complex function theory.